# How does the Castrol index works?

Tags: football

I've read some vague explanations of how the [Castrol Index](http://www.fifa.com/castrolindex/) works but none of them explain it in details. Does anyone knows how it works in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an Article from [uefa.com](http://www.uefa.com/news/newsid=631172.html#castrol+provide+perspective), you can read more from the link, but I think there won't be more in-depth data on the analysis and it's formulas.

> With raw match data provided via systems installed by UEFA in
>   stadiums, Castrol believe by implementing their own mathematical
>   formulae their index will provide the football audience with a new
>   perspective on the sport.
>
> **"It's based on missile technology with 16 cameras placed in the stadium gantry to monitor in real time the movements of 22 players,
>   three match officials and the ball," said Vijay Solanki**, head of
>   marketing services at Castrol Europe.
>
> "As a result it allows us to produce some amazing measurements we have
>   never had before in football. You can see the speed, distance run and
>   zonal movements of the players.

This is from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castrol_Performance_Index) page, but the reference links in wiki page are broken.

> The Castrol Index is a rolling ranking system that measures
>   performance of every football player across Europe's top five leagues
>   during the course of a 12-month period. Rankings are published
>   monthly.
>
> To get Castrol Index Ranking, first "**Castrol Index Score" is
>   calculated for every player in every league and Champions league
>   match, then the score weighted to get "Castrol Ranking points", and
>   lastly, cumulative points from every match during the 12-month period
>   are multiplied with 90 and divided by total minutes played**.
>
> Weightings are different in every league and are adjusted after every
>   season by strength of every league. For example, Champions league
>   knock-out stage has biggest weight.

Comment: I think they dont give the full explanation to not make his procedure questionable

Comment: @Pablo, also it is Castrol's business, so no one shares their business logic in depth with the public.